# How to get number of files transferred as a variable?

Tags: batch-file, copy, transfer, xcopy

```
xcopy /Y /E /H "C:\test1" "C:\test2"
```

Returns a number of files copied, how do I get that number as a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('xcopy /Y /E /H "C:\test1" "C:\test2" ') do (
  set copied_files=%%a
)
echo %copied_files%
```

not tested.

Comment: Just tested, his worked perfect. I can call this one solved, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @abelenky , will do that now and in the future.